# Calling button from another Activity

Tags: android, button, android-activity

How can I edit a button from another Activity?

It returns me an

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

When I want to

```
getButton.setEnabled(false);
```

where

```
Button getButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonGet);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have called setContentView before you get a reference to your button, i.e do this:

```
setContentView(R.layout.my_activity_layout);
```

before this:

```
Button getButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonGet);
```

Comment: What did he mean by 'another activity' then? :)

Comment: I think Coretek meant an xml layout file.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can, or at least it's not "the Android way(tm)".
Instead, either set a preferences flag and read it on your target activity's OnResume, or if the target (the one with the button) calls the other, you can return something with setResult(...) and read it in onActivityResult(...).

Edit: Looks like i answered what he said "call a button from another (i.e. different from current)" activity, but what he actually **meant** was that he couldn't find his buttons in the current one :)