# Button set Text Activity B

Tags: android, button, android-activity

I am From Cali Colombia no speak english ok

I have activityA  and activityB  a Button activityA 
click button set Text activityB  = setText ("100");

```
 public void onClick(View arg0) {


    Intent manu = new Intent (MainActivity.this,Sonido.class);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);                
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView21)).setText("100");

startActivity(manu);

/*
1.getText()
2.putString()
3.getString()

.take data from a string and show activity B
.The button is only in the activity
*/


}
```

question like mine:
[Calling button from another Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10685039/calling-button-from-another-activity)

Answer (score 2):

**-** Activity A and Activity B

**-** Activity B has a button mbutt.

Moving from Activity A to Activity B

```
A ----> B (B has button mbutt)
```

**In Activity A :**

```
Intent i = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
i.putExtra("key","100");
startActivity(i);
```

**In Activity B:**

```
Button mbutt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.myButt);
Intent intent = getIntent();
String value = intent.getStringExtra("key");
mbutt.setText(value);
```

Comment: public void onClick(View arg0) { 
 
 
    Intent manu = new Intent (MainActivity.this,Sonido.class); 
 
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);                 
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView21)).setText("100"); 
 
startActivity(manu); <--- this no write
 
/* 
1.getText() 
2.putString() 
3.getString() 
 
.take data from a string and show activity B 
.The button is only in the activity 
*/

Answer (score 0):

You can make an explicit intent for that. Put the string with an intent.putextra() method after you instantiate it. Get the string back in the other activity with settext.getextras(). Then you can use a switch statement if you want different but corresponding strings written the next activity.